# Android XML Generating NoSuchFieldError

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I recently updated my build.gradle to all of the latest android appCompat libraries and am receiving the below error message. It appears to be related to material design but I really don't understand what is causing the error:

```
04-18 20:35:57.227 2018-2018/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: com.sourcey.materialloginexample, PID: 2018
                                                                            java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field abc_ic_ab_back_material of type I in class Landroid/support/v7/appcompat/R$drawable; or its superclasses (declaration of 'android.support.v7.appcompat.R$drawable' appears in /data/data/com.sourcey.materialloginexample/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_4-classes.dex)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.<init>(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:91)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.getWrapper(Toolbar.java:1775)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.getDecorToolbar(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:538)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.pullChildren(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:530)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.setWindowCallback(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:606)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:384)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:300)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:264)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:129)
                                                                                at com.troychuinard.fanpolls.LoadingActivity.onCreate(LoadingActivity.java:26)
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6272)
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:157)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5527)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
```

Included is the associated XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
android:background="@color/logo_red"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.troychuinard.fanpolls.LoadingActivity">

<ImageView
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/fan_polls_logo"/>


    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/loading_spinnter_white"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/loading_text"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: ever got it resolved?